# How to report current usage for a user on ulimits aka pam_limits etc?

Tags: pam, limit, ulimit

Every SA sooner or later runs into a user hitting a ulimit like open files or number of processes.

There must be a simple mechanism to track and test against usage of these limits, or ulimits would be horribly inefficient.

So, how could an admin or a user see current usage versus their ulimits?

I do not need to hear `ulimit -Sa`, `ulimit -HA`, or side-effect/discovery methods like `lsof | grep $USER`. I would really hope for something like:

```
cat /proc/$$/task/$$/limits
```

Except there would be another column labeled "Current Usage".

Comment: Related: [How to check ulimit usage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230346/how-to-check-ulimit-usage)